# SSAS Time state rollup

Tags: ssas, average, cube, rollup

I have the following situation (in SSAS):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzkDS.jpg

- Cube with two dimensions (Time / Alpha) and one measure (X)

Columns A - G is the result of the cube, with column G as the total sum.

How to get the average (like column H) instead of sum in SSAS?

It's called "Time state rollup" in Cognos, but how to get this in Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the Measure Aggregation Function: AverageOfChildren.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply. When I try AverageOfChildren, the following ERROR occurred: Errors related to feature availability and configuration: The 'Semi-additive measures' feature is not included in the '64 Bit Standard Edition' SKU.

Comment: Yes that is correct - you need Enterprise or Business Intelligence Editions for that feature. There are probably MDX alternatives, but they are typically complex to implement and run much more slowly.

Comment: Basically, without the right edition, I don't get the average like sketched above in a neat solution?

Comment: Yes that's right. Before you start, I worked directly with Cognos for many years so I have a fair idea what it costs to get started on that stat - roughly 10 x SQL BI Edition.